# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable, while parsing JSON

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm working with flask. I have a flask function that receives some posted json and looks like:

```
@app.route('/index',methods=['POST'])
def index():

    import json
    json = request.get_json(force=True) # receives request from php
    for j in json:
            print str(j)
```

The printed json looks like:

```
{u'token': u'146bf00b2cb96e6c425c2ab997637', u'a': u'aaa'}
{u'token': u'146bf00b2cb96e6c425c2ab3f7417', u'a': u'bbb'}
{u'token': u'146bf00b2cb96e6c425c2ab3f5692', u'a': u'ccc'}
```

The number of json records that come in are variable. I need to load the values into a list of dictionaries that looks like:

```
[{u'token': u'146bf00b2cb96e6c425c2ab997637', u'a': u'aaa'},{u'token': u'146bf00b2cb96e6c425c2ab3f7417', u'a': u'bbb'} ....]
```

I've tried:

```
 test = [{'a': j[i]['a'], 'token':j[i]['token']} for i in len(json)-1]
```

However, this is giving me the error listed above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You already have a list; `json` is that list of dictionaries.

Comment: Remove `import json` as you are not using anything related to that lib

Comment: The dictionaries in the `json` list don't have `'ad'` keys, only `'a'` keys, is that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *need* to produce a list object because you already have that list. the `json` variable references it, which is why your `for j in json:` loop works in the first place.

Your error stems from trying to loop over an integer `len(json) - 1`:

```
test = [{'a': j[i]['ad'], 'token':j[i]['token']} for i in len(json)-1]
#                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Perhaps you wanted to use `range(len(json))` there? Not that there is a need to produce integers here, you could just loop over the `json` list again to extract what you want:

```
test = [{'a': entry['a'], 'token': entry['token']} for entry in json]
```

but this just creates copies of the already existing dictionaries, unless they have more keys you didn't include in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!